# Comparing two date times

Tags: c#

Say now is 13:12 PM and I want to see if it is earlier than 20:00 PM.... I get the current time using `DateTime.Now` but I format it as "h:mm tt" and I want to see if a given current time is say between 8:00 AM and 20:00 PM.

Comment: 20:00 PM is not a valid representation of time. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the `DateTime` objects directly r use the `Ticks` property to compare them. Below is a simple example demonstrating that

```
var dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact("8:00:00", "H:mm:ss", null);
var dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact("20:00:00", "H:mm:ss", null);

if (dt1 <= DateTime.Now && dt2 >= DateTime.Now)
    Console.WriteLine("Hooray");
```

Comment: not working... I used it like this: `var dt1 = DateTime.Parse("8:00:00");
            var dt2 = DateTime.Parse("20:00:00");

            if (dt1 <= DateTime.Now && DateTime.Now >= dt2) MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt"));
            else MessageBox.Show("No.");`
current time here is: 13:32 PM

Comment: @A.Ispas Not sure why it did not work for you, since it worked for me. My guess would be your locale settings are different than mine. I edited the answer to use `ParseExact`. Please try that. If that does not work, can you show the output of `DateTime.Now.ToString()` for you. Your focus should be actually on the `if` line and not the other lines

Comment: `if(DateTime.Now.Hour > 8 && DateTime.Now.Hour < 20)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("hooray");
            }` it works like this so its okay now. I figured it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code goes as under:

```
DateTime dtFrom = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(8);  // Use Current Date and set time to 8:00 AM
DateTime dtUpto = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(20);    // Use Current Date and set time to 20:00 (8:00 PM)
DateTime dtCurr = DateTime.Now;
if (dtFrom <= dtCurr && dtCurr <= dtUpto)
    MessageBox.Show(dtCurr.ToString("h:mm tt"));
else
    MessageBox.Show("No");
```

Comment: if(DateTime.Now.Hour > 8 && DateTime.Now.Hour < 20) { MessageBox.Show("hooray"); } it works like this so its okay now. I figured it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please you can check this way:

```
DateTime dt1;
          dt1 = DateTime.Parse("8:00:00");
        DateTime dt2;
          dt2 = DateTime.Parse("20:00:00");
    if (dt1 <= DateTime.Now && DateTime.Now >= dt2) 
        {
          MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt"));
        }
     else MessageBox.Show("No.");
```

Comment: `if(DateTime.Now.Hour > 8 && DateTime.Now.Hour < 20)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("hooray");
            }` it works like this so its okay now. I figured it out. Thanks.